How to return an object of any type without compile error: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to T
I've been using Spark Java framework in which data can be retrieved from a session like this, without any explicit type cast:
User user = req.session().attribute("user");
Item item = req.session().attribute("item");

I can
The attribute method of spark.Session looks like this:
    public <T> T attribute(String name) {
        return this.session.getAttribute(name);
    }

And the javax.servlet.http.HttpSession:
    Object getAttribute(String var1);

However when I try to reproduce this behaviour:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }

    public static <T> T hello(String key)  {
        return wow(key);
    }

    public static Object wow(String key)  {
        return "";
    }
}

I get an error:
java.lang.Object cannot be converted to T

How do I make my generic method work similarly to the attribute method? So that I could do
String name = hello("name");
List<String> names = hello("allnames");


T is not a known class, it can't convert it to it.

Declare public static <T> T  wow(String key) and have the method return (T) "" using an unchecked cast. You will have the problem in the form of a ClassCastException, of course, if you try Integer s = hello("myInt");  and the method returns a String and not an Integer.

I don’t know much about Spark, but hopefully it is evident that User user = req.session().attribute("user"); indicates a very bad design.

Hello @parsecer, maybe you can use public  T wow( String key ) {
return ( T ) "Parsecer";
}.

Long story short, you need to cast the result to T. Consider this simplified implementation of session:
public class Session {

  private final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

  public void setAttribute(String key, Object value) {
    map.put(key, value);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public <T> T getAttribute(String key) {
    return (T) map.get(key);
  }
}

The internal storage keeps everything as Object, so anything can be stored. getAttribute() casts the value to T (read that as whatever is required). The upside is that you do not need to do the casting yourself every time to get a value. But you need to be sure you know the correct type of whatever you extract, otherwise it will result in ClassCastException.
Session session = new Session();
session.setAttribute("a", 11);
session.setAttribute("b", "qwerty");
int intVal = session.getAttribute("a");//success
String stringVal1 = session.getAttribute("b");//success
String stringVal2 = session.getAttribute("a");//ClassCastException

